# CentOS7 サービスを停止させたところ起動しなくなりました

Tags: centos, google-compute-engine

こちらを参考に不要サービスを全て停止した後にrebootすると起動エラーとなり起動しなくなってしまいました。
http://qiita.com/dumpty-alma@github/items/091862834317229559f1
これをこのまま実行しました。

```
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable abrt-ccpp.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-ccpp.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable abrtd.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrtd.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable abrt-oops.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-oops.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable abrt-vmcore.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-vmcore.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable abrt-xorg.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abrt-xorg.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable atd.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/atd.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable auditd.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/auditd.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service 
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/avahi-daemon.service'
rm '/etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/avahi-daemon.socket'
rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable kdump.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/kdump.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable NetworkManager
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service'
rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.service'
rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable smartd.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/smartd.service'
[root@crown ~]# systemctl disable tuned.service
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tuned.service'
```

消去できないのもいくつかありますが、全て消したあとは普通に正常に動いていました。
なんとなくrebootすると起動できなくなりました。

GoogleConsoleを見ると

```
Sep  3 20:44:14 localhost google: Waiting for metadata server, attempt 328
Sep  3 20:44:15 localhost accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

というエラーが１秒ごとに連続で表示されています。

どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

もうひとつ考えられるのは、Nginxのworker_connectionsを1024から65535に変更しました。

unalistさんにチャットで１時間以上教えて頂いていたんですが、不可能でした。
GoogleCloudShellを使用していたのですが、/var/www/htmlにファイルが無く、もしかするとと思ったんですが、GoogleCloudShellは今のインスタンスとは全く関係のないものだったのかもしれません。

sshでnetworkをenableとかしていたんですが、SSH接続は不可能でした。

ディスクのスナップショットを作成し、そのスナップショットから新しいインスタンスを作成したんですが同じ症状で起動できませんでした。

Comment: OS入れ直したら直ると思いますよ。それが確実かと...
その手順のどこまでやったの？全部、途中？ホントにその手順だけやったの？
情報足りないままだとご所望の解は得られないと思います。

Comment: レスキューモードで起動できませんか? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Compute Engine を使っているのですね？

だとすれば、 Network Manager を止めたのが原因ではないでしょうか。このサービスはネットワークの設定を行うものですから、これを止めるとネットワークにつながらなくなります。

あなたが参考にされたQiitaの記事にも書かれていますね。

> 補足）NetworkManagerを停止すると、ifcfg-ens*で書いていたGATEWAY0が有効になってませんでした。
>   <sub>--- http://qiita.com/dumpty-alma@github/items/091862834317229559f1 より引用</sub>

で、 Google Compute Engine 上でこれをやってしまうと、起動時に行われる Google のサーバーとの通信が行えないために、エラーが出ているのだと思います。

類似の例
https://stackoverflow.com/q/28492368/2818869
https://stackoverflow.com/q/30915528/2818869

VPS等であればネットワークが死んでいても仮想コンソールから対処できると思いますが、GCEでそれができるのかはわからないです。もし無理であれば、VMを作り直すほかないかと。

---

仮想コンソールが使えたようなのでチャットで復活を試みていましたが、解決には至りませんでした。上記も可能性の一つではあると思うので残しておきますが、今回はこれが直接の原因ではなかったかもしれません。

Comment: 仰る通りできませんでした。再インストールしたいと思うのですが、MySqlのデータベースだけ復旧できれば良いのですが可能ですか？

Comment: 起動できなくなったVMからディスクを切り離し、新しいVMに割り当てることができるようなので、そこからmysqlのデータディレクトリも復元できるとは思います。ただ残念ながら、具体的な手順は知らないです。

Comment: すみません、仮想VPNでは接続できませんでしたが、GoogleCloudShellというので接続が出来ました。
sudo su -もできましたが、ここからどのようにして復元すればよいでしょうか

Comment: でしたら、`systemctl enable NetworkManager` を実行して再起動してみてください

Comment: 最初にrm で削除してしまいました。Operation failed no suchとなります

Comment: rmで消したのが `/etc/systemd/(略)` というファイルなら問題ないです。スペルミス等していませんか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27732/discussion-between--and-unarist)しましょう。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28759/discussion-between--and-unarist)しましょう。

Comment: 諦めました、諦めが付くようプロジェクトを削除しました。
長い間ありがとうございました。